# Creating n empty dataframes using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I want to create n empty dataframes using for loop.

Something like :

```
import pandas as pd

n=6

for i in range(0,n):

     df(i) = pd.DataFrame()
```

Output like:

```
  df1,df2,df3,df4........dfn
```

Comment: `[pd.DataFrame() for _ in range(n)]`

Answer (score 0):

You could store them in a list of dataframes:

```py
dfs = []

n = 6

for i in range(n):
    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame())
```

An alternative would be using a dictionary with meaningful names (these could of course also just be the numbers 1 to 6:

```py
names = ['df1', 'df2', 'df3']
dfs = {}

for name in names:
    dfs[name] = pd.DataFrame()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create dataframes and append them to a list:

```
df_list = list()
for i in range(6):
    d_one = pd.DataFrame()
    df_list.append(d_one)
```

Access individual dataframe by simply indexing normally:

```
df_list[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer for the example you gave is, you don't.
This is what collections (`list`s, `dict`s) are for.

With a comprehension it's a fairly trivial task.

```
# as a list
list_of_df = [pd.DataFrame() for _ in range(n)]
print(list_of_df[0])
```

If you still want to refer to them by their name it might make more sense in the form of a `dict`.

```
dict_of_df = {f'df{i}': pd.DataFrame() for i in range(1, n + 1)}
print(dict_of_df['df1'])
```

Although it is possible to modify the `dict` of `globals()`, if you use an IDE, your linter will hate you, and you'll be fighting it at every corner.

```
# don't do this
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    globals()[f'df{i}'] = pd.DataFrame()
print(df1)
```

It's a hackier way of creating your own `dict` and if you do do it you'll have to hard code the variable names anyway.